# Numpy Matrix Remove row that equals to an array

Tags: python, numpy, numpy-ndarray

I have a numpy matrix with 2 axis (row and columns) and an array.
I want to remove the row in the matrix that equals to the array.
For example, if the matrix is

> [[1, 2, 3],
> [4, 5, 6],
> [7, 8, 9]]

And the array is [1, 2, 3], then the output should be:

> [[4, 5, 6],
> [7, 8, 9]]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use:

```
a[~(a == b).all(1)]
```

---

Example:

```
a = np.arange(1, 10).reshape((3, 3))
b = np.arange(1, 4)

a[~(a == b).all(1)]
array([[4, 5, 6],
       [7, 8, 9]])
```